# What changed between Nikon D750 "C" firmware versions 1.02 and 1.12?

Tags: nikon, firmware, nikon-d750

I just found that there have been many firmware upgrades for my current Nikon camera after I bought it around 2 years ago.

The latest "C" firmware version available is 1.12, while I had 1.02.

I want to figure out what changed or improved from what I had before.

Please note that I can see the most recent change on their download page like this:

> Changes from “C” Firmware Version 1.11 to 1.12
>
> - Added support for the following features of AF-P lenses:
>
>   - If the standby timer expires after the camera has focused, the focus position will not change when the timer is reactivated.
>   - In manual focus mode, the focus indicator in the viewfinder (or in live view, the focus point selected in the monitor) will flash to show
>       that infinity or the minimum focus distance has been reached by
>       rotating the focus ring.
> - Fixed the following issues:
>
>   - When pictures were viewed after shooting with Overflow selected for Role played by card in Slot 2 in the PHOTO SHOOTING MENU, the
>       camera would sometimes display the second-last picture taken.
>   - Microphone sensitivity would sometimes not be correctly adjusted when movies were recorded with Auto sensitivity > Microphone
>       sensitivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The was information was there on the [Download Center page for the D750](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/245.html), you just didn't scroll down enough. Below the *Changes from “C” Firmware Version 1.11 to 1.12* section is another section:

> ## Changes from Previous Versions
>
> **Changes from “C” Firmware Version 1.10 to 1.11**
>
> **Changes from “C” Firmware Version 1.02 to 1.10**
>
> **Changes from “C” Firmware Version 1.01 to 1.02**

Collectively, there are numerous changes, too many to list here.

Comment: You are right. I missed it.